# Creating a 3-dimensional OrderedDict with natural subscripting

Tags: python, python-2.7, defaultdict, ordereddictionary

I want a dictionary structure which has the following properties:

1. Doubly nested (so, 3-dimensional in so many words)
2. Remembers the order of things added to it for each level

So, if I add items to it like so:

```
# d = something dict-ish
d['a']['b']['c'] = 'd'
d['a'][1][2] = 3
d['f']['g']['e'] = 'g'
d['f'][5][6] = 7
d['a']['foo']['bar'] = 'hello world'
```

The result of the following comprehension:

```
[(i, j, k, d[i][j][k]) for i in d for j in d[i] for k in d[i][j]]
```

Will be:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 1, 2, 3), ('a', 'foo', 'bar', 'hello world'), ('f', 'g', 'e', 'g'), ('f', 5, 6, 7)]
```

I've tried using a `defaultdict` to enforce this structure for new keys so I don't have to type it the long way, like so:

```
# long way
d = OrderedDict()
d['a'] = OrderedDict([('b', OrderedDict([('c', 'd')]))])
d['a'][1] = OrderedDict([(2,3)])

# tried to use defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: OrderedDict()))
d['a']['b']['c'] = 'd'
d['a'][1][2] = 3
```

But the `defaultdict` doesn't remember the order of the top two levels. I'm not sure how to merge the behavior, so obviously the top two levels are yielding `defaultdict` behavior because I have declared `d` to be as such. How can I achieve the structure I want?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, that's probably actually what I meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is to subclass `OrderedDict` and add a `__missing__` function:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class DefaultOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = type(self)()
        return self[key]
```

The *default* `dict` type will call a `__missing__` method if present before raising a `KeyError`, which is what the `defaultdict` type makes use of.

See the [`dict` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) (scroll down to the `d[key]` description):

> *New in version 2.5*: If a subclass of dict defines a method `__missing__()`, if the key *key* is not present, the `d[key]` operation calls that method with the key *key* as argument. The `d[key]` operation then returns or raises whatever is returned or raised by the `__missing__(key)` call if the key is not present. No other operations or methods invoke `__missing__()`. If `__missing__()` is not defined, `KeyError` is raised. `__missing__()` must be a method; it cannot be an instance variable.

Demo:

```
>>> d = DefaultOrderedDict()
>>> d['a']['b']['c'] = 'd'
>>> d['a'][1][2] = 3
>>> d['f']['g']['e'] = 'g'
>>> d['f'][5][6] = 7
>>> d['a']['foo']['bar'] = 'hello world'
>>> [(i, j, k, d[i][j][k]) for i in d for j in d[i] for k in d[i][j]]
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 1, 2, 3), ('a', 'foo', 'bar', 'hello world'), ('f', 'g', 'e', 'g'), ('f', 5, 6, 7)]
```

Comment: `__missing__`?! First time I'm seeing it. Awesome! Have a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The old fashioned way:

```
data = [('a','b','c','d'), ('a',1,2,3), ('f,'g','e','g'), ('f',5,6,7), (a','foo','bar','hello world')]

answer = OrderedDict()
for d in data:
    if d[0] not in answer:
        answer[d[0]] = OrderedDict()
    if d[1] not in answer[d[0]]:
        answer[d[0]][d1] = OrderedDict()
    if d[2] not in answer[d[0]][d1]:
        answer[d[0]][d1][d2] = OrderedDict()
    answer[d[0]][d1][d2] = d[3]
```

Comment: I had something very similar going on beforehand, but I think it was broken. This is better!